# Query on Generics in java

Tags: java, generics

I have recently started using generics in java, and in that attempt tried to refactor existing code of our team.

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with the following -

```
private ArrayList<? extends WorkTabPane> workTabPanes = null;
protected <T extends WorkTabPane> void addPane(T pane) {
    workTabPanes.add(pane);
}
```

Eclipse indicates an error at line 3(at add)  - "The method add(capture#1-of ? extends WorkTabPane) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (T)"

Comment: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you want to have just

```
private ArrayList<WorkTabPane> workTabPanes = null;
protected void addPane(WorkTabPane pane) {
    workTabPanes.add(pane);
}
```

(You can still add subclasses of `WorkTabPane` to the list.)

The reason eclipse complains is the following: By writing `<? extends WorkTabPane>` you say "This is a list of some specific class which happens to extend WorkTabPane". This variable could for instance contain a reference to a `ArrayList<WorkTabPaneSubclass1>`. However, if that's the case, then you should not be be allowed to add items of type `WorkTabPaneSubclass2` to the list. You see the problem?

Comment: Actually, the method signature should probably just be `protected void addPane(WorkTabPane pane)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
private ArrayList<? extends WorkTabPane> workTabPanes = null;
```

This says `workTabPanes` is a list that is guaranteed to contain instances of `WorkTabPane` or one of its subclasses, so when reading from it you know that's what you get. It may however be a list of `WorkTabPaneSub`s, in which you can't put regular `WorkTabPane`s.

You need:

```
private ArrayList<WorkTabPane> workTabPanes = null;
```